# vfork:Understanding Issue:

Tags: operating-system, system-calls

I have a confusion around the functionality of `vfork()`. I read that in case of `vfork()`, parent and the child process used to share pages between them. It doesn't support any copy on write functionality. This means, if during its timeslice child process makes some changes, all these changes would be visible to the parent process when it will return. It was also mentioned, that the `vfork()` syscall is only been useful when the child process just executes the `exec` system call after its creation.

Let us say, that the child process executes the `exec` system call with `ls`. Now, according to the `exec` calls, the `ls` program will be loaded on to the address space of the child process. Now, when the parent process' timeslice will start, it might have a different intruction to execute on its PC, which might cause this process to behave differently.

Can somebody please make this scenario clear to me, how the `vfork()` call is helpful in such situations?

Comment: Not entirely; note that the answers to that are all at a higher level, whereas this question needs a lower level view.

Comment: @Learner: I replaced timestamp with timeslice in your question - hopefully this is what you meant. If not, please feel free to edit again.

Answer (score 1):

The point of `vfork()` is not to allocate a new address space for a child which is going to immediately throw it away again.  As such, `vfork()` omits the part of `fork()` which creates a new address space (page tables and allocations) for the child, and instead sets a flag which `execve()` interprets as meaning that it should allocate a new page table and stack for the process before populating it with the new executable and its requested initial heap (BSS).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so it means that **"execve"** sytem call used to behave differently in case of **vfork()**. Normaly, it overwrites the binary image of the calling process, but in case of **vfork()**, it creats new address space for executing its job. Correct me, if i am wrong.

Comment: @Learner: That's mildly wrong. `execve` always creates a new page table, stack, etc. The old ones are normally destroyed at the same time, but if they're shared with another process (the parent) they'll just have that shared reference decremented.

Answer (score 0):

`execve()` releases the current process' memory mappings and allocates new ones. Exiting a process also ends up releasing that process' memory mappings.

Traditionally, `vfork()` suspends the parent process until the child stops using the parent's memory mappings. The only way to do that safely is via `execve()` or `_exit()`.

> Let us say, that the child process executes the exec system call with
>   ls. Now, according to the exec calls, the ls program will be loaded on
>   to the address space of the child process.

Actually, `ls` will be loaded in a new address space, the parent's address space is released on the child.

Comment: Thanks for the reply on my query. Your reply makes me understand the "geekosaur" reply better now. But i would still like to ask more about **execve** system call. I read that **execve()** system call overlays the current process image with a new process image, but according to your reply, it removes the older one and allocates a newer one. Can you please, update me on the same again?